# which layer in multi-tier enterprise application can implement security constraints .

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

In a multi-tier enterprise application . Which layer can implement security constraints so that the data and application's resources can be protected from hackers . What are the technologies which can implement these constraints . What can be done to implement security in UI's and Address bars.

Comment: I suggest reading https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-intro001.htm

Comment: What if I wanted to implement security using Spring Application framework .

Comment: Then your question is missing the spring tag or any indication that you are using Spring

Answer (score 1):

A simple tip at first: Don't implement it on your own, but rely on proven frameworks doing it for you and learn to use them the right way.

Concerning the layer question: Your application can do many things to support security and it's always a good idea to think about the possible vulnerabilities and the harm that can be done with it. But usually, your application is not responsible for dealing with attacks - this should be done before the call even reaches your application. So in a productive environment, you have several security zones, for example a web server, an application server and a database, and all of them are protected by a firewall which control the possible access paths of your servers.